# Fontsawesome Icons are not working in HTML file using links

Tags: html, css, icons, web-development-server

I have been tired of writing code  but the icon is not shown on the Web page, I have tried changing the background still not seen.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and consider updating your question with a [mre] of your current code. There are many ways to handle importing and using FA but we need to see your code to see how you're doing it and then go from there :)

Answer (score 0):

to add fontawesome icons, you first need to make an account on https://fontawesome.com.

Once you made an account, then simply go to https://fontawesome.com/kits to make a new kit for your project. It is very easy to make a new kit on their. All you need is to just follow the instructions given by them.

Finally you will be able to see something like "Add Your Kit's Code to a Project". Copy kit code from there and paste it in the header part of your HTML file.

Here is an example of how to link it to your HTML file. (Please note that this won't display anything because this is not a valid fontawesome kit.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/YOUR_OWN_KIT_CODE.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <i class="fas fa-cloud" style="font-size:48px;color:red;"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks and best regards!